# How can we run two functions in different enclaves in parallel?

Tags: sgx

I'm a beginner of Intel SGX. I was wondering whether SGX supports running two functions in different Enclaves in parallel? E.g., Function A is in Enclaves En_A, and Function B is in Enclaves En_B. Is it possible that an application calls Functions A and B in parallel?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

> The SGX design supports having multiple enclaves on a system at the
>   same time, which is a necessity in multi-process environments. This is
>   achieved by having the EPC split into 4 KB pages that can be assigned
>   to different enclaves. The EPC uses the same page size as the
>   architecture’s address translation feature.

[(source)](https://gts3.org/pages/enclave-layout.html)

Looking at the [Intel SGX SDK docs (page 92)](https://01.org/sites/default/files/documentation/intel_sgx_sdk_developer_reference_for_linux_os_pdf.pdf) you can see that `sgx_create_enclave` function distinguishes enclave instances by taking unique `enclave_id`:

```
sgx_status_t sgx_create_enclave (
    const char *file_name,
    const int debug,
    sgx_launch_token_t *launch_token,
    int *launch_token_updated,
    sgx_enclave_id_t *enclave_id,    // here
    sgx_misc_attribute_t *misc_attr
);
```

These enclave ids are used by the application to make ECALL calls using untrusted proxy functions:

```
// demo.edl
enclave {
    trusted {
        public void get_secret([out] secret_t* secret);
    };
}

// generated function signature
sgx_status_t get_secret(sgx_enclave_id_t eid, secret_t* secret);
```

You can find a complete explanation on [page 27](https://01.org/sites/default/files/documentation/intel_sgx_sdk_developer_reference_for_linux_os_pdf.pdf)